# How can I display all the lines that end with a certain character using grep?

Tags: unix, grep

I want to write a command to display all the lines in a given file that end with a "`;`" or a "`.`" character.

Why does this not work?

```
grep ".';' | .'\.'" filename
```

Comment: I fixed your titles so they were actually meaning something. It would be great – if you post a question – to make your title really specific about what you want to do, not "Unix grep".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep "[;.]$" list-of-files
```

This matches any line which contains either `;` or `.` followed by the end of the line.

Comment: .. how does this work ?

Comment: @ricedragon  it's regex notation.  [abc] means a or b or c.   $ means match end of line.  play with regex coach and see http://www.regular-expressions.info/  and grep -P is a bit more flexible.